# Connection String Debug

Tags: winforms, ms-access, connection-string

I guess my question is how do you debug a connection string?

Background Info

- Dev Machine is 64bit but I have my build targeting 32bit
- Windows Form App targeting .NET 2.0
- Has an embedded access database to hold look up values and store some basic information
- In App.config

  add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source   =C:\Development\MyFolder\MyAccessData.mdb;"

As soon as I hit F5 it sets a breakpoint on this line:

```
connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Stewie thanks for the reply. Apparently my issue was due to the fact that "Target Any CPU" on a 64bit machine defaults to 64bit and OleDb is only 32 bit.

Comment: does it work with .Tostring() at the end or .Connectionstring;?